# Displaying derived attributes of gpx track in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, gpx, tracking

When adding a GPS track, I see the "output" attributes (as in the attached picture). At the same time, I do not see this data in the attribute table. How can I enable visibility of this data in the attribute table?

[image]

Comment: This data is related to the geographic properties of your data. There are many ways to use this data/create explicit fields. Which field data do you need and for which purpose.

Comment: I need the coordinates and the length on the ellipsoid. I want to calculate the instantaneous velocity at a point. Distance between points / time difference = speed at the second point.

Comment: @АлександрБ. According to your comment, you don't need these attributes directly, you are solving a completely different problem (velocity determination). Break your question into parts (how to find the length of the line, how to find the velocity at a point), look for answers to them, and if you don't find them, ask new questions.